# How to list all subdirectories with certain date pattern in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a directory that has subdirectories like `FEB2014, MAR2013`, etc. It also could have subdirectories like Log or something else.

My question is how to find all subdirectories with certain date pattern (for my case is `MMMyyyy`) like `FEB2014, MAR2013`. I prefer using `LINQ`.

Comment: are you only looking one level deep?

Comment: Your examples don't match the date pattern you've given; did you mean `MMMyyyy`?

Comment: sorry my bad, should be MMMyyyy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  like:

```
DateTime temp;
var filtered = directories.Where(r => DateTime.TryParseExact(r, 
                                        "MMMyyyy", 
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                        DateTimeStyles.None, 
                                        out temp))
            .ToList();
```

This will return only those directories which have name with format `MMMyyyy`. Consider if your `directories` array consist like:

```
//string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories("yourPath");
string[] directories = new[] 
    {
        "FEB2014", 
        "MAR2013", 
        "LOG", 
        "SOMETHING", 
        "APR2014",
        "MAY2014"
    };
```

The above query will return four records.

```
FEB2014
MAR2013
APR2014
MAY2014
```

For your comment:

`DirectoryInfo.GetDriectories` returns an array of `DirectoryInfo` object, not a string name directly. Also you need to pass a `DateTime` object for out parameter, You can do the same like:

```
DateTime temp;
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(MyApp.App_Code.Global.FileLocation)
                    .GetDirectories()
                    .Where(d => DateTime.TryParseExact(d.Name, 
                    "MMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                    DateTimeStyles.None, 
                    out temp))
                    .OrderBy(d => d.LastAccessTime).Last();
```

Comment: I tried dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(MyApp.App_Code.Global.FileLocation).GetDirectories() .Where(d=>DateTime.TryParseExact(d, "MMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out new DateTime())).ToList() .OrderBy(d => d.LastAccessTime).Last(); But I got an error on TryParseExact

Comment: @GLP, edited the answer with your requirement. You will get an array of `DirectoryInfo` objects from your method , not an array of strings. Try the edited code and let me know if it works.